# Django registration form gives error, when password can not pass validation

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to make user registration with automatic login. When passwords are different or do not pass validation, there is no message from the form. It throws an error:

```
AttributeError at /accounts/register/
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I think the error comes from the `login(request, self.object)` line. I have tried to fix the problem with overriding the `clean()` method in the form, but it did not work. I am not sure what to do.

my model:

```
class AppUser(auth_models.AbstractBaseUser, auth_models.PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = AppUserManager()
```

my form:

```
class SignUpForm(auth_forms.UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = (UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD, 'password1', 'password2',)
        field_classes = {
            'email': auth_forms.UsernameField,
        }
```

my view:

```
class SignUpView(views.CreateView):
    template_name = 'accounts/user/register-user-page.html'
    form_class = SignUpForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        login(request, self.object)

        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `form_valid()` instead of `post()`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def form_valid(self, form):
    user = form.save() #save the user
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```